# Unique rows which have the max element on the last column in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix with the same rows which are different only in two columns, like this:

```
A = [2 3 3 3 1 0.7;
     2 3 3 3 2 0.4;
     3 2 2 2 1 0.8;
     3 2 2 2 3 0.3]
```

Now I need to select unique rows which have the same elements of column1,2,3,4 and have the maximum elements in column6, like:

```
Response: [2 3 3 3 1 0.7;
           3 2 2 2 1 0.8]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sort according the first 4 columns, and in descending order according to 6th. Then, pick first occurrence within groups decided by first 4 columns.

```
out     = sortrows(A,[1:4,-6]);
[~,idx] = unique(out(:,1:4),'rows');
out(idx,1:5)
```

Comment: That doesn't work, since there's no guarantee that you hit the correct value for row #5

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply!!! Can you please tell me how can I remove last column in my "out" variable? I mean what should I do if I want to have 5 column (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) in out?

Comment: @user2286747: you write `out(:,1:5)`

Comment: @Jonas: Many thanks for your prompt reply!! I am new in Matlab so can you please let me know more about your comment? Why it doesn't work?

Comment: @OlegKomarov: The sortrows approach is nice. +1. You may want to mention that `unique` has recently changed its behavior (it used to pick the last row before).

Comment: @OlegKomarov: Thanks, you mean just this: out     = sortrows(A,[1:4,-6]);
[~,idx] = unique(out(:,1:4),'rows');
out(idx,1:5)

Comment: @OlegKomarov: Also, why not just delete the other approach?

Comment: @jucestain How should I do this?!

Comment: There should be a a grey check sign that you can click under the upvote/downvote arrows which are next to the body of the answer.

Comment: @OlegKomarov I did, tnx. :)